# Two White Wires, one red, one black on a lightswitch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

I'm getting rid of this old hideous lightswitch with a nicer looking paddle switch. It only goes to one light.

White at the top right and bottom right, red at the bottom left, black at the top left.

I'm assuming I should wire nut the two whites together in the back of the box, and then with the new switch put black on gold and red on silver? Is that right or do I need a different kind of lightswitch for this with more terminals?

[image: Lightswitch]

Comment: It is very unusual to have more than 2 wires (not counting possible green or bare ground) ion a light switch *unless* it is a 3-way or 4-way switch. **Do any other switches control the same light?**

Comment: There is one other switch that controls the light.

Comment: 1 - We need to know what other wires (if any, but likely at least one) are in this box. 2 - We need to know what wires are connected to the *other* switch. 3 - There is quite possibly *another* switch, because 4-wires is normally on a 4-way, which is normally *in between two 3-way switches*.

Comment: It depends on how the switch is being used. If this is a double-pole, double-throw, then there will be two inputs and two outputs (a 240v switched circuit for a heater or motor, etc.) If if is a 4-way, then it is just swapping travelers. If you put in the wrong switch, there may be a short when you switch it.

Comment: Okay, probably not a short, but the switch won't do what you want if it is the wrong kind.

Comment: Before you change it, after you've turned power to the circuit off and pulled the switch out from the box, but before you remove any wires from the switch, take more pictures, and do something to identify which white wire is which. Make sure your pictures show where all the wires come from and go it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a 4-way switch. [called 3-way outside of North America] That normally works with 2 3-way switches [called 2-way outside of North America] and as many more 4 way switches as needed for the desired number of switches to control a light. The fact that you only *know* of one more location might mean you haven't noticed the other 3-way switch, or that things have been modified since the original installation.

Your safest bet is to get another 4-way switch and wire it up exactly like this one. At bare minimum you need a 3-way switch to have two switches controlling one light, but since that is NOT what you presently have, it might require considerable investigation to determine what wires to use on it.